# ANGULAR PETICION HTTP ENVIAR FILE + JSON

Tags: angular, angular9

tengo una api rest que recibe un JSON, pero necesito también pasarle un archivo, como podría hacer para enviar en la misma petición el JSON + el archivo?

Este es código que tengo actualmente, si en vez de formData le paso el json, se envía el json correctamente pero el Archivo, y si paso el formData se pasa el fichero pero no el JSON.

```
prueba(json: any, file: File){
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('json', json);
formData.append('image', file, file.name);

return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost/tus_comercios_en_casa/kitum_rest_service/public/api/kitum/prueba', formData, {
  headers: {
    'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest'
  }
}).pipe(map(data => {
  return data;
})); }
```

Comment: En algunos servicios con los que he trabajado el archivo se envia como String en un campo de la estructura json, los bytes del archivo son Codificados en Base64 y se convierten en String, desconozco si es buena o mala práctica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El valor del método `.append()` no acepta el tipo de dato `Object` por lo que tendría 2 caminos para lograrlo: Convertir en `string` y decodificar en el servidor o recorrer el objecto y agregar una a una las propiedades al `FormData`.

1. Convertir en `string`:

```js
prueba(json: any, file: File): Observable<any> {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('image', file, file.name);
  formData.append('json', JSON.stringify(json));

  const endpoint = 'http://localhost/tus_comercios_en_casa/kitum_rest_service/public/api/kitum/prueba';

  return this.http.post<any>(endpoint, formData, {
    headers: { 'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest' }
  });
}
```

2. Iterar el objecto:

```js
// const json: any = {
//   field1: 'lorem ipsum',
//   field2: 'lorem ipsum'
// };

prueba(json: any, file: File): Observable<any> {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('image', file, file.name);
  Object.entries(json).forEach(([ key, value ]) => {
    formData.append(key, value as string);
  });

  const endpoint = 'http://localhost/tus_comercios_en_casa/kitum_rest_service/public/api/kitum/prueba';

  return this.http.post<any>(endpoint, formData, {
    headers: { 'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest' }
  });
}
```

---

La información se encuentra en la documentación:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Comment: El problema es que el JSON que envió no es un JSON sencillo, es un JSON mas complejo, `{
  "parameter_1": {
    "campo": "Rte El Buey",
  },
  "parameter_2" : {
   "campo" : "MARJAN S.L",
  },
  "parameter_3" : {
   "pick_up" : true,,
   "sub_1" : [
    {
     "campo": "ddd"
    }
   ],
   "sub_2" : [
    {
     "campo": "ddd"
    }
   ]
  }
}` es algo así

Comment: En este caso o bien se puede envíar el JSON como string `JSON.stringify()` o crear una función recursiva que tome cada una de los elementos del JSON y los envíe en el `.append()` con el formato: `formData.append('parameter_1[campo]', 'Rte El Buey')` o `formData.append('parameter_3[sub_1][campo]', 'ddd')`.